# Transaction MYSQL : Prevent READ from Table

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking

How i put transaction in MY-SQL similar to MS-SQL ?

In **MSSQL** : if i start a transation , another process cant read from table until is commited .

For ex : 
Thread 1 : START TRANSACTION   ON TABLE 1 
Thread 2 : SELECT FROM TABLE 1  :  WILL until Thread 1 commits
Thread 1 : COMMIT
Thread 2 : RETURNS DATA

IN **MYSQL** 
Thread 1 : START TRANSACTION   ON TABLE 1
Thread 2 : SELECT FROM TABLE 1  :  **RETURNS DATA**
Thread 1 : COMMIT
Thread 2 : RETURNS DATA

I need this as the process generates a unique  sequence and its returning duplicates when multiple requests are made at same time.

Thanks.